# check for empty values in JavaScript for datatypes like Array, Object, String and Number

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, is-empty, isnullorempty

I need to check whether enter parameter is empty or not like php `empty` function works.

For example, if I have function with name `isEmpty` and I passed `string` as parameter to it then function will return `true` if string is empty else `false` and similar for other datatypes like `Object`, `Array` and `Number`.

Comment: did you try something so far ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let isEmpty = param => {
 let isAnObject = (obj) => {
  if (obj == null) return false;
  return obj.constructor.name.toLowerCase() === "object"
 }
 if (Array.isArray(param)) {
  return !param.length;
 }
 if (isAnObject(param)) {
  return !Object.keys(param).length;
 }
 return !param;
}
console.log('Is empty Array: ',isEmpty([]));
console.log('Is empty Array: ',isEmpty([1,2,3]));
console.log('Is empty Object: ',isEmpty({}));
console.log('Is empty Object: ',isEmpty({a: 'I am not empty'}));
console.log('Is empty String: ',isEmpty(''));
console.log('Is empty String: ',isEmpty('I am string'));
console.log('Is empty Number: ',isEmpty(NaN));
console.log('Is empty Number: ',isEmpty(100));
console.log('Is empty String parse as number: ',isEmpty(parseInt('')));
```

I have created a function and named it as `isEmpty`. This function will return true if passed parameter is empty else false.

Comment: what is this ? part of your question ?

Comment: All of those conditions/approaches are actually in Stackoverflow, so this is unnecessary.

Comment: php have inbuild `empty` function that will check the enter parameter is empty or not irrespective of it's datatype but JavaScript do not have such function that will works like php empty function works.
But above provided function will works for all datatypes as developer required such type of code that will help or say reduced their work. So I have created this function. Thanks

Comment: The first two tests could be replaced with a single `==` comparison to `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: In javascript "typeof" function is there,using this you can get which type of data is as parameter.

Comment: Please check what is type of `null`, `infinity`, `[]` and `parseInt('')`. There are many cases that could not resolved by JavaScript `typeof` function.

Comment: Need such kind of code as a part of JavaScript inbuilt functionality. Code is correct and works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the "empty" things are *falsy* in JS, so it can be simplified to:

```
const isEmpty = thing => typeof thing === "object" ? !thing || !Object.keys(thing).length : !thing && thing !== 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Below solution works for me.

```
let code = (function(){
    return {
        isEmpty: function(param){
            return typeof param === "object" ? !param || !Object.keys(param).length : !param && param !== 0;
        }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let jqcc = (function(){
 var checkEmptyValues = function(param) {
  if (param == null) {
   return false;
  }
  if (Array.isArray(param)) {
   return !param.length;
  }
  if (param.constructor.name.toLowerCase() === "object") {
   return !Object.keys(param).length;
  }
  return !param;
 } 
 return {
  isEmpty: function(param){
   return checkEmptyValues(param);
  }
 }
})();

console.log(jqcc.isEmpty([]));
```